# Symfony 2 many-to-many sql translate to dql

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm having a problem with mapping a many-to-many relationship I've never encountered before. I have two entity document, exam, and relation many-to-many document2exam.

Information:

Entity/Document.php,
class Document {

```
private $id;
private $entryNumber;
private $isPaymentFree;
private $profile;
private $dateCreated;
private $dateModified;
private $exams;
private $invoice;
```

}

Entity/Exam.php

class Exam {

```
private $name;
private $examCode;
private $dateTime;
private $startOnlineRegDate;
private $endOnlineRegDate;
private $endChangeDate;
private $session;
private $link;
private $documents;
private $isWriting;
private $examService;
```

}

Resources/Document.orm.xml

```
    <many-to-many field="exams" inversed-by="documents" target-entity="\Entity\Exam">
        <join-table name="document2exam">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="document_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" on-update="CASCADE" on-delete="CASCADE" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="exam_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" on-update="CASCADE" on-delete="CASCADE" />
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all />
        </cascade>
    </many-to-many>
```

Resources/Exam.orm.xml

```
    <many-to-many field="documents" mapped-by="exams" target-entity="\Entity\Document" />
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT en.entry_number, en.exam_id 
FROM Data_ExamNotes en 
WHERE exam_id = 3 
    AND en.entry_number NOT IN ( 
        SELECT d.entry_number
        FROM Document d
            INNER JOIN document2exam d2e ON d.id = d2e.document_id
        WHERE d2e.exam_id = 3 
            AND d.entry_number is not null
    )
ORDER BY en.entry_number ASC
```

I cant write dql query because of document2exam table.

Thank you, and sorry for my language :)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            "SELECT en.entryNumber as enNum, IDENTITY(en.exam) as ex
                FROM UcictDataBundle:ExamNotes en 
                WHERE en.exam = :exam 
                    AND en.entryNumber NOT IN (
                        SELECT d.entryNumber
                        FROM UcictStudentBundle:Document d
                            INNER JOIN d.exams e
                        WHERE e.id = :exam 
                            AND d.entryNumber is not null                   
                    )
                ORDER BY en.entryNumber ASC");

        $ret = $query
               ->setParameter('exam', $exam)
               ->getResult();
        return $ret;
```